# Ember Actions: Using Variables Action Names

Tags: ember.js

From the Ember Documentation, I've been looking at this:

`<div class='intro'>
      {{intro}}
    </div>
    {{#if isExpanded}}
      <div class='body'>{{body}}</div>
      <button {{action 'contract'}}>Contract</button>
    {{else}}
      <button {{action 'expand'}}>Show More...</button>
    {{/if}}`

Note - that all the action names refer to a hardcoded value such as 'expand'.

What I would like to do is something like this:

`<button {{action variable}}>Show More...</button>`

where variable is defined in the controller or model.

Has anyone tried to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works out of the box

```
<div {{action foo}}> Click Me</div>

App.IndexController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  foo:'bar',
  actions:{
    bar: function(){
      alert('bar');
    },
    baz: function(){
      alert('baz');
    }
  }
})
```

Example (change the input box from bar to baz): http://emberjs.jsbin.com/beyesawe/1/edit

Comment: Thank you, I was overthinking it ;)